# Dynamically select and alias columns in Databricks based on a list or dictionary?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a vast amount of raw delta tables in Databricks (bronze), and I want to clean them up by only selecting a few columns and renaming them appropriately (before saving them to a new database; silver).

For example:

```
df.select(col("CUSTOMERNUMBER").alias('CustomerNumber'),
                col("NAME1").alias('CustomerName'),
                col("LANGUAGE").alias('Language'),            
                col("TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP").alias('TransactionTimestamp'))
```

However, I want to create a function that takes in a df and mapping and does the select dynamically.

Something along the lines like this:

```
mapCustomer = {'CUSTOMERNUMBER' : 'CustomerNumber', 
'NAME1': 'CustomerName', 
'LANGUAGE' : 'Language', 
'TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP': 'TransactionTimestamp'}

def map_col(df, mapping):
    return df.select(mapping)

mapped_df = map_col(df, mapCustomer)
print(mapped_df)
# save df to new location (Silver layer)
# mapped_df.write.format('delta')....
```

How can one achieve this?

I am getting an error:

```
Invalid argument, not a string or column: {'CUSTOMERNUMBER': 'CustomerNumber', 'NAME1': 'CustomerName', 'LANGUAGE': 'Language', 'TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP': 'TransactionTimestamp'} of type <class 'dict'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work:

```
def filter_data(df, mapping):
    mylist = []
    for key in mapping:
        mykey = key
        value =  mapping[key]
        mylist.append(col(key).alias(value))
    return df.select(mylist)

mapCustomer = {'CUSTOMERNUMBER' : 'CustomerNumber', 'NAME1': 'CustomerName', 'LANGUAGE' : 'Language', 'TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP': 'TransactionTimestamp'}
filtered = filter_data(added_col, mapCustomer)
display(filtered)
```